# Searchkick in another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I am a newbie in Ruby on rails, please help me solve my problem.

I already use gem searchkick, and in console I can get the result.

this is my code

route.rb

```
resources :m_customers

resource :patient, except: [:index, :show] do
  collection do
    get 'autocomplete'
  end
end
root :to => 'home#index'

get 'patient/PatientList', to:'patient#PatientList'
get 'patient/PatientList/autocomplete', to:'patient#autocomplete'
get 'patient/PatientHistory/:kode/:histid', to:'patient#PatientHistory', as: 'patient/PatientHistory'
get 'patient/PatientSub/:id', to:'patient#PatientSub', as: 'patient/PatientSub'
get 'patient/PatientObj/:objid', to:'patient#PatientObj', as: 'patient/PatientObj'
get 'patient/PatientAsses/:assid', to:'patient#PatientAsses', as: 'patient/PatientAsses'
get 'patient/PatientPlan/:planid', to:'patient#PatientPlan', as: 'patient/PatientPlan'
```

m_customer.rb => model

```
class MCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :Cust_ID

  searchkick match: :word_start, searchable: [:Cust_Name, :Cust_ID]
  MCustomer.search "tipping poi"
 end
```

patient_controller.rb

```
 class PatientController < ApplicationController
   require 'will_paginate/array' 
   def PatientList
      @date_now = Time.now
      @patients = TRegistration.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7).where(:Reg_status => 'N') 
      @patient2s = TRegistration.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 7).where(:Reg_status => 'P')

      if params[:query].present?
        @MCustomers = MCustomer.search(params[:query])
      else
        @MCustomers = []
      end
   end

   def autocomplete
     render json: MCustomer.search(params[:query], autocomplete:true, limit: 10).map do |customer| {name: customer.Cust_Name, value: customer.Cust_ID}
     end
   end
 end
```

when I go to the page below, I can find the result from searchkick :

```
     //localhost:3000/patient/PatientList/autocomplete?query=s
```

but when I inserted serch input, nothing could be shown

PatientList.html.erb

```
      <div class="cust-search">
        <%= form_tag patient_PatientList_path, method: :get do %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query], class: 'form-control twitter-typeahead' %>
            <%= submit_tag 'Search', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

java script patient.js

```
 var ready;
  ready = function() {
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
          return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: { url: '../patient/PatientList/autocomplete?query=%QUERY' }
  });

  // initialize the bloodhound suggestion engine

  var promise = engine.initialize();

  promise 
  .done(function() { console.log('success!'); })
  .fail(function() { console.log('err!'); });

  // instantiate the typeahead UI
  $( '.twitter-typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'Cust_Name',
    source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(ready);
  $(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

please help. thanks anyway.

Comment: I think you can find enough details in the github page:  https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

Comment: I already read the link, I've tried it but still show nothing. when will autocomplete is called?

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code should look like if you want a working autocomplete (only the relevant parts)

m_customer.rb (you should really consider naming it just customer)

```
class MCustomer < ActiveRecord::Base
   searchkick autocomplete: ['Cust_Name']
 end
```

you should use the autocomplete option and provide the column you want to autocomplete, e.g: cust_name

patient_controller.rb ( you should really consider naming it customer_controller )

```
 class PatientController < ApplicationController

   def autocomplete
     render json: MCustomer.search(params[:query], autocomplete:true, limit: 10).map do |customer| { name: customer.Cust_Name }
     end
   end
 end
```

here you are formatting your json response

patient.js (read this carefully and see the modifications)

```
  var engine = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: function(d) { 
          return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.name); },
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: { url: '/patient/autocomplete?query=%QUERY' }
  });

  var promise = engine.initialize();

  $( '.twitter-typeahead').typeahead(null, {
    name: "customer",
    displayKey: "name",
    limit: 20,
    source: engine.ttAdapter()
    });
  }
```

I think this is where you made your mistake, you should provide the right key so the method will read your json as it should and retrieve the names you want.

you should check out this wonderful guide, you can read and just copy-paste with the modifications that suit your code:
https://rubyplus.com/articles/4031-Autocomplete-using-Typeahead-and-Searchkick-in-Rails-5

hope it helps anyone